# Elasticsearch Multipal queries with limit

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write an Elasticsearch query where I match multiple words in my title and description. The below code works fine but it gives all the articles matching those words. My aim is I need 4 articles per query word for e.g. 4 results of Tim Cook and four articles of Steve Jobs

```
{
  "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query":   ["Tim Cook","Steve Jobs"],
            "fields": ["Title", "Description" ],
            "operator":"AND"
         }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. Maybe you can exemplify by showing what results you get now and what results you want to receive.

Comment: I need 8 results form a single query of which 4 results should be of Tim Cook and four results should be of Steve Jobs.

Comment: `{
  "query": {
    
        "multi_match": {
            "query":   ["Tim Cook"],
            "fields": ["Title", "Description" ],
            "operator":"AND"
            }
      
     },
  "size" : 4
},
{
  "query": {
    
        "multi_match": {
            "query":   ["Steve Jobs"],
            "fields": ["Title", "Description" ],
            "operator":"AND"
            }
      
     },
  "size" : 4
}`  I tried the above code it only returns the result for first query.

Answer (score 1):

[Top hits aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) are what you are looking for - 
Basically give 2 [filter aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) and then nest top hits aggregation side them.

So something like below should work fine

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": [
        "Tim Cook",
        "Steve Jobs"
      ],
      "fields": [
        "Title",
        "Description"
      ],
      "operator": "AND"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "tim": {
      "aggs": {
        "top_hits": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "query": {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": [
              "Tim Cook"
            ],
            "fields": [
              "Title",
              "Description"
            ],
            "operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "steve": {
      "aggs": {
        "top_hits": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "query": {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": [
              "Steve Jobs"
            ],
            "fields": [
              "Title",
              "Description"
            ],
            "operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want top hits I just need latest entries. 4 entries of each keywords.

Comment: Top hits gives you that